# First Gen vs Second Gen prolong in Honorverse

Tags: honorverse, prolong

In the [Honor Harrington](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honor_Harrington) series by David Weber they keep talking about life extension via Prolong.  They distinguish between First Generation recipient and Second Generation recipient.

I am trying to figure out if that means they have V1 and V2 of the Prolong process or whether they mean, your parents had it (First generation) then you got it (second generation).  Or something else entirely?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"generation" refers to the generation/step of the technology, not the demographics of the users.

From "[prolong](http://honorverse.wikia.com/wiki/Prolong_Treatment#Treatment_Generations)" on HH Wikia:

> The first generation of prolong slowed the aging process at early middle age. The treatment had varying effects depending on the recipient's genetic makeup. (HH1) This treatment became available to the Star Kingdom of Manticore in the early 19th Century PD (likely after 1830 PD), with King Roger III being the first Manticoran Monarch to receive the treatment.
>
> The second generation both increased longevity as well as slowed the aging process in the mid to late 20s. This generation also removed much of the varying effectiveness. (HH1) The treatment was available on Beowulf before 1840 PD as Allison Chou Harrington was a Second-Generation Prolong recipient. (HH2)
>
> In 1900 PD, the newest generation of aging treatments was the third generation. It improved on the longevity of the second generation as well as slowed the aging process in the early 20s. This prolong treatment worked universally well. Honor Harrington was one of the earliest Manticoran citizens to receive the Third-Generation treatment, implying it became available to the Star Kingdom of Manticore around 1860 PD. (HH1)

---

For a slightly more authoritative answer:

http://www.davidweber.net/faqs/index/series:3

> **Please explain prolong. What generation is Honor Harrington?**
>
> There are currently three generations of prolong. The term "generation" has nothing to do with descent or parentage; it refers to the version or variant of prolong available.

Please note that the FAQ is on David Weber's official homepage, not a fansite.

Comment: While this is correct, it may be worth noting that there is a correlation between which prolong treatment someone received and their actual age simply because the later treatments *didn't exist* when older people received the first generation treatment. Thus, younger people are more likely to have received later versions due to being born later. This may be contributing to the OP's confusion.